# Изменить название шапки

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал калькулятор вклада с сохранением.

Как заменить `Diposit-название программы` на `[имя вклада]-задаёт пользователь при создании вклада`

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл решение:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diposit_layout);
    setTitle("[имя вклада]"); //меняет имя шапки
}
```